# Compare two images

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, mobile, windows-mobile

I have a grid of Images, I click one, I search for this image on that grid "2D array of Images"
then I want to check if this image is the one I need,
the images in the grid are:

```
BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Mines1.2;component/Images/new.png", UriKind.Relative));

Image temp = new Image();
temp.Height = 50;
temp.Width = 40;
temp.Source = img;
temp.Name = i.ToString() + j.ToString();
temp.MouseLeftButtonDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(this.explore);
```

explore is the function I want to go when click on the image.

I want to compare now the image temp with another one, I do this with it's resource uri

```
if(temp.source.equals(new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Mines1.2;component/Images/new.png", UriKind.Relative))))
```

but this does not work! 
I want to check if two images are the same or not using the uri or source or anything but of course I'm not going to check each pixel.

Answer (score 3):

you could create a hash of the file and then compare whether the two hashes are the same.